# MySQL upsert with find or create on separate table

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, upsert

I have the following query to perform a bulk upsert into an attributions table. I'm wondering how I can modify it to first perform a bulk find or create on a partners table using a `name` attribute (name is unique on partners), and then use the ID returned as the `partner_id` in this query below. `partner_id` is a foreign key on attribution.

```
      INSERT INTO attributions (count, partner_id)
        VALUES
          (1,1),(1,1),(1,1)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          count = count + 1
```

Is it possible to do this in one query or will I need two separate ones, to first get the ID's of the new/existing partners, and then create the attributions using these partner ids?

Comment: I'd do it in two queries. It may be possible to do it in one, but that would make your code harder to maintain. There's an advantage in designing code to be easy to work on.

Comment: If doing it in two queries, be sure to wrap it up inside a transaction.

Comment: See this for high speed insertion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table